# IP address starts with 169

Tags: static-ip

My Raspberry Pi 3 with is running Raspbian GNU/Linux 9.8  (stretch) has the wlan0: inet that starts with a 169 in the IP address. I know that this an IP address that is given when the DHCP cannot give me a different IP address. I am connected to the network from my house and the network settings on my device are not showing connection issues. Pings are host unreachable with 169. 
Any Ideas of what can fix the IP address. I've already reboot twice.

Please help

Comment: Is there a DHCP server running on your network? What is the ip address range of your home network? Something like 192.168.?.?